# How To Save Image in My WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

In My WPF application i am not able to save image inside my application in snap folder. Below is the code i am using.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp"; 
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string filepath = ofd.FileName;
            File.Copy(ofd.FileName, Application.StartupPath + "\\snaps\\" + ofd.SafeFileName,true);
            photoTextBox.Text= ofd.SafeFileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);

        }
```

Comment: you want to save, or you want to open?

Comment: I wanna save it in Snap folder inside my application and then display it immediately in Image control

Comment: Do you get an exception? Or it just doesn't load in the Image control?

Comment: dutzu when i am not able to save inside my application ,i am not able to write the code similar to my traditional window app

Comment: I am Not able to understand why these guys are marking this question wrong ,Is something out of the way i asked ??????

Comment: What is the difference between your `WPF application` and your `Simple window application`?

Comment: @nitin-sharma You are being down voted because "i am not able to write the code" and "i am unable to achieve" are completely meaningless to to rest of us and do not describe any kind of a problem. If your images are not being saved, then use your debugger and check your file paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code to open the file browser

```
 string filepath;
        //browse Button
        private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Multiselect = false;    
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            bool? result = open.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                filepath = open.FileName; // Stores Original Path in Textbox    
                ImageSource imgsource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filepath)); // Just show The File In Image when we browse It
                Clientimg.Source = imgsource;  
            }
        }
```

And below is the code used for saving the file

```
private static String GetDestinationPath(string filename, string foldername)
        {
            String appStartPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

            appStartPath = String.Format(appStartPath + "\\{0}\\" + filename, foldername);
            return appStartPath;
        }
```

How to use it

```
string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);
string destinationPath = GetDestinationPath(name,"YourFolderName");

File.Copy(filepath, destinationPath, true);
```