# How to save uploaded image to custom folder in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am very new to `C#`. I am doing some self studies. I did one small CRUD App using `Windows Form Application`. It's working fine. Now I want to do one like that in `WPF`. I realized, some functions, methods are not same as `WFA`.

Now I want to know how to save the uploaded image to a custom folder.

I have created folder in my `Solution` called `Uploaded`. I know how to Upload, Resize the images. Now I want to save this resized image to that Cutome Folder.

Here is my event.

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string imagepath = ProfilePicURL.Text;
    string picname = imagepath.Substring(imagepath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
    //Rename the file as per the user first and last name 
    picname = FirstName.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty) + "_" + LastName.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

}
```

Comment: Check if this link can be useful to you. Let us know if it works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099869/how-to-save-image-in-my-wpf-application

Comment: @RobertLangdon Thanks. I also use this. It's taking me to the `bin/Debug`+`DestinationFolder`. I want to save it Inside my Solution Explore. Please advise me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: Then try move up two levels from `bin/debug` to make it your solution folder : `appStartPath = String.Format(appStartPath + @"\..\..\{0}\" + filename, foldername);`

Comment: Thank you guys @har07 and RobertLangdon

Answer (score 0):

```
    string imagepath = ProfilePicURL.Text;    
    var imageFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(imagepath);
    if (imageFile.Exists)// check image file exist
    {
        // get your application folder
        var applicationPath=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        // get your 'Uploaded' folder
        var dir=new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(applicationPath,"uploaded"));
        if(!dir.Exists)
            dir.Create();
        // Copy file to your folder
        imageFile.CopyTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir.FullName,string.Format("{0}_{1}",
            FirstName.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty),
            LastName.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty))));
    }
```